# JDialog does not display proper text

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, joptionpane, jdialog

I'm creating an About dialog for my program and have run into an issue. Whenever I launch the dialog, the title text sets properly, but the text inside the dialog says "JOptionPane Message". Before it wouldn't even show the label I added to the dialog, but that fixed itself (I'm not entirely sure how) but now it displays both the added text and the "JOptionPane Message".

Code for the dialog:

```
    about.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
            JOptionPane optionPane = new JOptionPane();
            JDialog dialog = optionPane.createDialog("About");
            JLabel aboutText = new JLabel("Text goes here", JLabel.CENTER);
            dialog.add(aboutText, BorderLayout.NORTH);
            dialog.setVisible(true);
        }
    });
```

So the text works now, which is nice. But how do I get rid of the part that says "JOptionPane Message"?

Comment: The question is, what's wrong with `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, aboutText, "About", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);` ?

Comment: The problem with that is I'd like the end result to be a logo centered on the dialog, with the about text displayed underneath of it. Is there a way I can do that with showMessageDialog()? I searched a bit but couldn't find anything

Comment: Yes.  You can use HTML to format the `String` or use the `JLabel` as the message object to the option pane...

Comment: So I'm assuming the proper way to do this would be `JLabel labelName = new JLabel("Text here", imgIcon, JLabel.CENTER);`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what you do to procure the about dialog. Plus, it's only one line of code!

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Text goes here", "About", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
```

I assume that this code is inside a subclass of `JFrame`. If not, replace `this` with any component inside the window where you want to dialog to appear, or just `null` for the center of the screen.

You may also want to change "Text goes here" to your own custom message text.

To change the type of message, change `JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE` to one of the following:

- `JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE`
- `JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE`
- `JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE`
- `JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE`

Comment: That would depend on what you want to achieve ;) - Nothing wrong with your answer in general though

Answer (score 3):

I think people forget just how powerful `JOptionPane` can be...

If you supply a `String` as the `message` `Object`, `JOptionPane` will create a `JLabel` to display it with, if you supply some kind of `Component`, `JOptionPane` will simply use it instead, for example...

[image]

```
JLabel label = new JLabel("Bring it on");
label.setIcon(new ImageIcon("logo.png"));
label.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
label.setVerticalTextPosition(JLabel.BOTTOM);
label.setHorizontalTextPosition(JLabel.CENTER);
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, label, "About", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, thank you! Setting @tbodt's response as the solution, as it's more relevant to the original question. I didn't know about `setIcon()` and if I'm not mistaken you can only use one label in `showMessageDialog()` which is why I went for JDialog. Thanks again!

Comment: @ThomasRamage See my Answer for why this was occuring, Also you can still give upvotes as well as accepting an answer to show that it was still useful.

Comment: @ThomasRamage That would depend on you needs.  You could just as easily pass `JOptionPane` a `JPanel` with other components added to it, for example...

Comment: Unfortunately I can't upvote until I've reached 15 reputation. Is it poor etiquette to come back once I've obtained enough reputation to give upvote? I'm a bit new to SO

Comment: @ThomasRamage Welcome and Apologies, I forgot about the requirement to upvote. No It would not be poor etiquette. I Suggest you take the time to read through the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) as to was is generally accepted/not accepted.

Answer (score 1):

This occurs because you are using the default constructor `new JOptionPane()`. From the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html#JOptionPane%28%29):

> Creates a JOptionPane with a test message.

This test message is `"JOptionPane Message"`

If you use the constructor `new JOptionPane("A Message")` then the message will become `"A Message"` where this constructor is taking an Object so using a Label your code would become

```
JLabel aboutText = new JLabel("Text goes here", JLabel.CENTER);
JOptionPane o = new JOptionPane(aboutText);
JDialog dialog = optionPane.createDialog("About");
dialog.setVisible(true);
```

You can also use the constructor `new JOptionPane(null)` to have no object or default message so you can add them later if you like.